# Configuring Delphi XE 8 to publish APP on iPhone iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, delphi, delphi-xe8

I have the following environment: **- Windows 7 64 bits - Delphi XE8 - Oracle Virtual Box with Mountain Lion - Google Developer Account -Apple Developer Account**

I am trying to set up as TARGET iOS DEVICE - 64 bit.

But the target list is empty, does no show the list of devices.

See the image below when I select iOS DEVICE - 64 bit

[image: TARGET LIST on DELPHI's PROJECT MANAGER]

For Iphone emulator it works fine. I meant, when i send to the emulator the APP works fine, but I cannot publish using iOS DEVICE.

Can anyone help here?

Comment: Did you read the [Running Your iOS Application on an iOS Device](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Running_Your_iOS_Application_on_an_iOS_Device) documentation?

Comment: Yes I did, but there there is no explanation for my question.I really dont understand. Do you have a direct answer for my question?

Comment: I already gave you a direct answer - READ THE DOCUMENTATION. If no device shows up in the list, then either there is no device connected to begin with, or you have not configured the IDE/project correctly to communicate with it. The documentation is very detailed on how to set that up. If you don't think it is working correctly, then you need to post the exact steps you took to setup your IDE/project for iOS.  You likely missed a step.

Comment: In the iOS emulator works fine, but I cannot launch the APP in the iPhone. I saw videos on youtube where people can publish direct on the iPhone using debug mode. I really don't understand why does not show the devices in the list. That is not explained in the documentation.

Comment: Why show the devices in the iOS emulator and does not show the devices in the iOS DEVICE target? I already tried 02 devices: iPhone and iPAD, the Itunes opens automatically when i connect the devices, but does not show in Delphi Target List

Comment: Um, because the setup needed to communicate with an iOS **simulator** is different than the setup needed to communicate with an iOS **device**, and because the devices supported by the iOS **simulator** are built-in to the IDE without it having to hunt for them, unlike a physical device which is discovered dynamically as it is plugged in and removed.

Comment: See the page Remy linked above, in the heading *Steps to Run Your App on an iOS Device*. It gives you **step by step** instructions, with links to detail pages for every single step. Follow them.

Answer (score 0):

See the official documentation:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Running_Your_iOS_Application_on_an_iOS_Device

> **Steps to Run Your App on an iOS Device**
>   Connect your iOS device to your Mac with an Apple USB cable
>
> **Run the Platform Assistant on the Mac**.
>       Test the connection to your Mac (on the Connection Profile Manager page).
>       Connect an iOS device (such as an iPhone or an iPad) to your Mac using the Apple standard USB cable (illustrated on the right).
>
> Note: Your iOS SDK version does not need to match the iOS device version. You can use the latest version of the iOS SDK and run your application on older iOS versions that RAD Studio supports. You should always use the latest version of the iOS SDK version.
>
> In RAD Studio:
>           In the Project Manager, expand the Target Platforms node and double-click the iOS device target platform that matches the architecture of your device, either iOS Device - 32 bit or iOS Device - 64 bit. The selected target platform is displayed using a bold font.
>           In the Target Platforms node, expand the selected iOS device node, expand the Configuration node, and double-click the Development platform configuration to select it. The selected platform configuration is displayed using a bold font.
>
> Note: You cannot run applications directly from RAD Studio into an iOS device if you build them with the Ad hoc or the Application Store platform configurations. To run applications deployed for ad hoc distribution, see Deploying Your iOS Application for Ad hoc Distribution. To run apps built for the App Store, you must submit them to the App Store and install them from the store.
>
> Run your app, either with debugging (Run > Run) or without debugging (Run > Run Without Debugging).
>
> RAD Studio builds your app using the SDK that you previously added to the IDE, connects to your Mac using the connection profile that you configured for the selected iOS device target platform, and the Platform Assistant on the Mac launches your application on the connected iOS device.
>
> **Notes:**
>   The first time that you use a user account on your Mac to run an application on an iOS device, your Mac will prompt you to allow RAD Studio to sign applications using your private key. You must accept this on your Mac so that RAD Studio can continue running your application on your iOS device.
>
> RAD Studio might look frozen at some points until it launches your app on your iOS device, but it is just preparing to run your app.